# UTF-8 / Unicode Text Encoding with RPostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql, encoding, utf-8, rpostgresql

I'm running R on a Windows machine which is directly linked to a PostgreSQL database. I'm not using RODBC. My database is encoded in UTF-8 as confirmed by the following R command:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING")
#   client_encoding
# 1            UTF8
```

However, when some text is read into R, it displays as strange text in R.

For example, the following text is shown in my PostgreSQL database:
"Stéphane"

After exporting to R it's shown as:
"StÃ©phane"
(the **é** is encoded as **Ã©**)

When importing to R I use the `dbConnect` command to establish a connection and the `dbGetQuery` command to query data using SQL.  I do not specify any text encoding anywhere when connecting to the database or when running a query.

I've searched online and can't find a direct resolution to my issue.  I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167298/rodbc-character-encoding-error-with-postgresql), but their issue is with RODBC, which I'm not using.

[This link](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) is helpful in identifying the symbols, but I don't just want to do a find & replace in R... way too much data.

I did try running the following commands below and I arrived at a warning.

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")
# [1] ""
# Warning message:
# In Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8") :
#   OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8" cannot be honored
Sys.setenv(LANG="en_US.UTF-8")
Sys.setenv(LC_CTYPE="UTF-8")
```

The warning occurs on the `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")` command.  My intuition is that this is a Windows specific issue and doesn't occur with Mac/Linux/Unix.

Comment: Note that `client_encoding` is *not* the actual encoding used by your database. You can find the encoding for a database using the `psql -l` option or the `\l` command.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> After exporting to R it's shown as: "StÃ©phane" (the é is encoded as Ã©)

Your R environment is using a 1-byte non-composed encoding like latin-1 or windows-1252. Witness this test in Python, demonstrating that the utf-8 bytes for `é`, decoded as if they were latin-1, produce the text you see:

```
>>> print u"é".encode("utf-8").decode("latin-1")
Ã©
```

Either `SET client_encoding = 'windows-1252'` or fix the encoding your R environment uses. If it's running in a `cmd.exe` console you'll need to mess with the `chcp` console command; otherwise it's specific to whatever your R runtime is.

Comment: Yes this works.  I ran the command `postgresqlpqExec(con, "SET client_encoding = 'windows-1252'")` before loading the data from PostgreSQL, and even though the system returns `FALSE`, it still converts to the desired character.  Thanks!

Comment: @DavidL Just be aware that if you take that approach, and your data contains chars that cannot be represented in windows-1252, queries will fail with encoding errors. If possible it'd be *better* to get your R environment using Unicode instead.

Comment: How to set your R environment using Unicode instead?

Answer (score 18):

As Craig Ringer said, setting `client_encoding` to windows-1252 is probably not the best thing to do. Indeed, if the data you're retrieving contains a single exotic character, you're in trouble:

> Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :    RS-DBI
>   driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  character 0xcca7 of
>   encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in "WIN1252" )

On the other hand, getting your R environment to use Unicode could be impossible (I have the same problem as you with `Sys.setlocale`... Same in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632751/best-practice-should-i-try-to-change-to-utf-8-as-locale-or-is-it-save-to-leave) too.).

A workaround is to manually declare UTF-8 encoding on all your data, using a function like this one:

```r
set_utf8 <- function(x) {
  # Declare UTF-8 encoding on all character columns:
  chr <- sapply(x, is.character)
  x[, chr] <- lapply(x[, chr, drop = FALSE], `Encoding<-`, "UTF-8")
  # Same on column names:
  Encoding(names(x)) <- "UTF-8"
  x
}
```

And you have to use this function in all your queries:

```
set_utf8(dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT myvar FROM mytable"))
```

---

**EDIT:** Another possibility is to use [RPostgres](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RPostgres) unstead of RPostgreSQL. I tested it (with the same config as in your question), and as far as I can see all declared encodings are automatically set to UTF-8.

Comment: I can confirm that using RPostgres solves the problem.

Comment: Both Postgres and the set_utf8 solutions worked very well.

Answer (score 4):

If you use RPostgres::Postgres() as the first parameter of dbConnect() normally you will not have problem with encoding.

I tried this script where I had the same problem and now my accented characters are ok.

```
dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),user="user",password="psw",host="host",port=5432,dbname="db_name")
```

Answer (score 1):

This will fix any Unicode/UTF-8 problems in Windows. It must be executed before querying the database.

```
postgresqlpqExec(con, "SET client_encoding = 'windows-1252'")
```

<sub>*Drawn from asker's misplaced self-answer, visible in question revision history*</sub>

Comment: @Scarabee: I checked before posting and Craig's had less detail about this, mentioning only that there would need to be some R-runtime-specific way to set `client_encoding`.

Answer (score -1):

Do it:

```
con <- dbConnect("...", encoding = "latin1")
```

Comment: I get Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  unused argument (encoding = "latin1")